# JQuery Validation - Show/Hide a label rather than use its message

Tags: jquery, validation

I can't figure out the errorPlacement method of the jQuery validation plugin - for use with my checkboxes anyway. I want to just make the script show/hide a label if there's an error.

Does anyone know where I put my code to be triggered when the validation finds an error? I *think* I can use success: to make it hide the label.

This is just for one element, so I need to be able to specify it somehow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the [invalidHandler and submitHandler](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) hooks to provide your custom behavior.  This will allow you to override the default mechanisms for showing/hiding errors.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I was after !